# Kubuntu 14.04 missing some network settings

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, vpn, settings

I'm trying to set up a VPN, but I am missing any VPN settings in my network settings. (I have a picture)

[image]

Why am I missing these settings? I just did a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too because regular Ubuntu works differently than Kubuntu.

Kubuntu has the VPN settings in the "connection editor", which is not in the regular network settings. If you click on the current network connection (ie WiFi) in the area at the lower right corner of the desktop, then click the "wrench" icon at the top right of the popup, you will launch the connection editor, where you can add/edit VPN connections.